# PHP ClassA::load() must be compatible with InterfaceA::load()

Tags: oop

I have some classes:

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
     public function load(Foo $foo) {

     }
}


interface InterfaceA {
     public function load(InterfaceFoo $foo);
}

class Foo implements InterfaceFoo
{

}
```

My question is why is my ClassA::load(Foo $foo) method not compatible with my InterfaceA::load(InterfaceFoo $foo) even though class Foo implements InterfaceFoo?

I know I can write my ClassA as follows:

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceA {
     public function load(InterfaceFoo $foo) {
             if (!($foo instanceof Foo)) {
                 throw new Exception("InterfaceFoo must be an instance of Foo");
             }
     }
}
```

but I still am confused why the previous way doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do that because it violates the InterfaceA contract.

`load` method says it can work with any concrete implementation of InterfaceFoo, not only the specific one. 
This is called polymorphism and is good.

You can dinamically downcast foo param in your load method to check if it's some concrete implementation like Foo.

Comment: Like I did in the second part? where I check `if (!($foo instanceof Foo)) {`